# C# don't accept '\' in replace function

Tags: c#, split

I want to split a process filepath by "\", but C# don't accepting '\'.

```
string[] pathSplit = p.MainModule.FileName.Split(new Char[] { '\' });
foreach(string path in pathSplit)                        
{
}
```

I got this error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsfxb.png

The string doesn't end.
Where is my problem?

Comment: Backslash in C# (`\`) is an escape character.  to use it as a literal do as @GrantWinney suggested, or (if it is a string, which it's not in this case) use the `@` to make a literal string - i.e., `string myString = @"This is a string with \ a backslash";`

Comment: Perhaps you need to read the section on [string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx) on the C# reference

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `'\'` char in string or char literals.

You can just use `@'\'` instead to tell the compiler you need a `'\'`